# terminal goes down with all children even when SIGKILLed but normal processes don't do the same

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, systems-programming

I would like to have the same effect in my program as the bash(terminal) does when we kill it using SIGKILL. As we know that we cannot handle SIGKILL in our progams so when ever I kill my program its children are assigned to init process, there is no way to handle it so that I can kill all my child processes and then kill the parent itself. Though when ever we kill terminal all the process created through it are killed even if we kill our terminal by SIGKILL.

For this I did some research and found the below post:
[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54963/how-can-terminal-emulators-kill-their-children-after-recieving-a-sigkill][1]

The post is bit confusing, still what I got out of the post is that if the process you are killing is the process leader of the process group then all its children will be killed.

So for simplicity, I implemented below program to test if it is so:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Curent PID: %u\n", getpid());

    // make a new session
    pid_t pid = setsid();

    printf("New session ID: %u\n", pid);

    pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
            case -1:
                    perror("UNable to fork the process\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            case 0:
                    // child process
                    while (1)
                    {
                            sleep(1);
                    }
                    break;
    }

    while (1)
    {
            printf("Process Leader running\n");
            sleep(1);
    }

return 0;

}
```

After running the above program when I killed the parent process the child process didn't got killed. I also modified the above program so that it does not belong to any tty, I thought might be the process leader should not be associated with any tty. I did that by the following way:

Create a normal process (Parent process)

Create a child process from within the above parent process

The process hierarchy at this stage looks like :  TERMINAL -> PARENT PROCESS -> CHILD PROCESS

Terminate the the parent process.

The child process now becomes orphan and is taken over by the init process.

Call setsid() function to run the process in new session and have a new group.
then the same above code repeats.

Still when i killed the process leader children were there.
Maybe I didn't got that post on unix.stackexchange or is it the deafult behaviour in LINUX.
One way that I can implement to make all children kill is by catching each TERMINATING SIGNAL like SIGTERM, SIGHUP etc. handle them and write logic inside those signal handlers to kill child first.But still on SIGKILL I can't do anything.

Also I am interested to know that if killing parent process doesn't affect child process even if the parent is process leader or whatever then how bash(terminal) manages to kill all the child processes even if we send SIGKILL to it. Is there some extra logic written for terminals in LINUX kernel.

If there is a way to kill all child processes when parent is killed even using SIGKILL signal, I would be happy to know that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual page of kill says:

> Negative PID values may be used to choose whole process groups

In my understanding to kill the whole group of processes, you have to send negative PID.

Another mechanism is causing that killing a terminal kills its child processes. Processes running from a terminal have their stdin/stdout attached to the terminal. When killing the terminal, those connections are closed and a signal (SIG_HUP) is sent to those processes. A usual program does not handle this signal and is terminated by default.

Comment: thanks for updating me on kill and showing how to kill process tree...do you know any way to kill all child processes when SIGKILL is received through C program.

Comment: In my understanding SIG_KILL is actually not "received" by the process. If the OS is asked to send SIG_KILL, it terminates the process and the process itself can't execute any action.

Comment: Just to confirm, because I don't want to get it wrong..you are sure that closing of stdin/out connections generates that SIGHUP...

Comment: After a small google search, the following link may give you answers: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html. Concerning SIG_HUP it says: `If termination of a process causes a process group to become orphaned, and some member is stopped, then all are sent first SIGHUP and then SIGCONT.`

Answer (score 1):

The advice from Marian is quite correct and well worth researching, but if you choose to follow that route you will likely end up with an implementation of what might be called the "hostage trick".

The hostage trick consists of your root process spawning an artificial child process which spends all its time in the stopped state.  This "hostage" will be spawned immediately before the first child process which does real work in your (multi-process) program.

The hostage process is made the leader of its own process group and then enters a loop in which it stops itself with "raise(SIGSTOP)".  If it is ever continued, it checks to see whether its parent has terminated (i.e. whether it has been re-parented or cannot signal its parent with the null signal (ESRCH)).  If the parent has terminated, then the hostage should terminate, otherwise it should re-suspend with another "raise(SIGSTOP)".

You need to be careful about race conditions: e.g. for the re-parenting test take care to cache the parent-process-id for the hostage as the return value from "getpid()" before "fork()"-ing the hostage and also make "setpgid()" calls downstream of "fork()" in both parent and child.  You then need to consider what you do if someone "kill(., SIGKILL)"s the hostage!

True, you can put a SIGCHLD handler in the parent to re-spawn it, but that requires considerable care to preserve the continuity of the identity of the hostage's process group; maybe there were other child processes at the time of the SIGKILL and the replacement hostage should go in the original process group, maybe there weren't and the original process group has evaporated.

Even if you get that right, the fact that you have put a "fork()" call in a handler for an asynchronous signal (SIGCHLD) will likely open another can of worms if your main process uses multiple threads.

Because of these difficulties I would advise against using the hostage trick unless the child processes run code over which you have no control (and to think seriously about the costs in complexity and maintainability even then).  If you have control of the code of the child processes, then it is much simpler to use a "pipe()".

You create the pipe in the parent process and manage the file descriptors to ensure that the parent process is the sole writer and that each child process allocates one file descriptor to the read-side.  If you do this, then the termination of the parent process (whether due to SIGKILL or any other cause) is communicated to the child processes by the EoF condition on the read side of the pipe as the last writer terminates.

If you want to treat SIGKILL specially, then you can use a protocol on the pipe whereby the parent process sends a termination message advising the children of its termination status on all normal terminations and on catchable fatal signals, and leaves the children to infer that the parent was killed by SIGKILL in the event that the read-side of the pipe delivers an EoF without a preceding termination message.

Comment: today i understood what you said...creating a pipe is a better convenient way got you..

Answer (score 0):

On Linux `prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG`... will arrange for a process to receive a signal when it's parent dies, this setting is preserved over `exec` but not inherited by child processes.